# React useState Updating Issues

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have another react state issue.

I am trying to set a modified file name in state before I then us it in axios. I have this...

```
useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
  async startUpload(data) {
          setFileName(
               `${projectID}-${basecampProjectID}/${data.Surname}${data.Firstname.charAt(0)}/${
                     data.Surname
                }${data.Firstname.charAt(0)}-selftape-${filedate}.${fileExtension}`
           )

          const params = {
            fileName,
            fileType,
            basecampProjectID,
          }
```

However it does not set the `fileName` state before it starts a following axios get.

I have run into a similar problem before and I had to use `useEffect`, but I cannot get this to work now.

EDIT: To be specific as opposed to other questions. I have put the

```
setFileName(
               `${projectID}-${basecampProjectID}/${data.Surname}${data.Firstname.charAt(0)}/${
                     data.Surname
                }${data.Firstname.charAt(0)}-selftape-${filedate}.${fileExtension}`
           )
```

in useEffect, but it does not get the data for some reason. I would be grateful for an advice

Comment: State updates are asynchronous. Use a local variable: https://pastebin.com/3mJF1bqP

Comment: thanks TJ Crowder, I was getting an eslint error that the name had already been declared, but it seems to work thanks so much!

Comment: Some ESLint rules are better than others. :-) If it bothers you, again, just use a different name. :-)